# Performance of copying/merging arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, performance, matrix

I need to merge two double matrices in Java and I am aware of

`public static double[] copyOf(double[] original, int newLength)`which is defined in the class `java.util.Array`

But I am concerned about the runtime because I need the most efficient outcome in terms of runtime which is of course ideally O(1) but I guess the operation is O(n) or even worse?

Can anyone provide advise?

---

Supplemental

I just realized that this method only applies to vectors (double[]) and need matrices. Any ideas are appreciated.

What I want to achieve is having the following:

let `m1` and `m2` be double matrices such as

`m1` =

```
[1,2,3]
[4,5,6]
[7,8,9]
```

and `m2` =

```
[3,2,1]
[6,5,4]
```

then I want to have a double matrix `m3` which is

```
[1,2,3]
[4,5,6]
[7,8,9]
[3,2,1]
[6,5,4]
```

Comment: Give us a hint on how you store matrices and what outcome should you get after merge. It'll be simpler to help you then.

Comment: It's still unclear, how do you orginize it in memory? Do you use 1D array, which has matrix packed by rows/columns or do you use 2D arrays? (Which are not good for the task.)

Comment: @marc wellman: Pleas see my edit.

Comment: @DenisKulagin: I have the same opinion.

Answer (score 1):

```
use System.arrayCopy(src,src start index,destn,destn start index,destn length)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using **ArrayUtils** .

```
int m[] = (int [])ArrayUtils.addAll(x,y);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use native **System.arraycopy** for sure. It has O(n) complexity, but works really fast due to processor-level support of such operation.

**java.util.Arrays.copyOf** will do as well - it's implemented using System.arraycopy.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that you can find an O(1) algorithm this task.

I am almost sure that your complexity will be O(n).

Answer (score 0):

If you need a dense matrix then it would be easier to allocate a big chunk of `array[]` of size M x N and wrap it in a Matrix class which can translate matrix(r, c) into `array[r*C + c]`.

This way you will do only one array copy operation for the internal `array[]`.

Something like this:

**EDIT**: Added row-major matrix concatenation using `System.arraycopy()`:

```
package example;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Matrix {
    private double[] array;
    int R;
    int C;

    Matrix(int R, int C) {
        this.R = R;
        this.C = C;
        this.array = new double[R * C];
    }

    Matrix(double[] array, int R, int C) {
        this.R = R;
        this.C = C;
        this.array = array;
    }

    Matrix(Matrix that) {
        this.R = that.R;
        this.C = that.C;
        array = Arrays.copyOf(that.array, that.array.length);
    }

    public void set(int r, int c, double value) {
        assert (r >= 0 && r < R);
        assert (c >= 0 && c < C);
        array[C * r + c] = value;
    }

    public double get(int r, int c) {
        assert (r >= 0 && r < R);
        assert (c >= 0 && c < C);
        return array[C * r + c];
    }

    public static Matrix concatRows(Matrix m1, Matrix m2) {
        double[] array = concat(m1.array, m2.array);
        Matrix m = new Matrix(array, m1.R + m2.R, m1.C);
        return m;
    }

    private static double[] concat(double[] array2, double[] array3) {
        int aLen = array2.length;
        int bLen = array3.length;
        double[] C = new double[aLen + bLen];
        System.arraycopy(array2, 0, C, 0, aLen);
        System.arraycopy(array3, 0, C, aLen, bLen);
        return C;
    }

    public void print() {
        for (int r = 0; r < R; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < C; c++) {
                double v = get(r, c);
                System.out.print(String.format("%.3f ", v));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] a1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
        Matrix m1 = new Matrix(a1, 3, 3);
        m1.print();

        double[] a2 = { 3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4 };
        Matrix m2 = new Matrix(a2, 2, 3);
        m2.print();

        Matrix m3 = Matrix.concatRows(m1, m2);
        m3.print();
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
1.000 2.000 3.000 
4.000 5.000 6.000 
7.000 8.000 9.000 

3.000 2.000 1.000 
6.000 5.000 4.000 

1.000 2.000 3.000 
4.000 5.000 6.000 
7.000 8.000 9.000 
3.000 2.000 1.000 
6.000 5.000 4.000
```

Basically, unless you can ensure that that matrix is immutable, you can only resort to deep-copy of the whole matrix. So the order is still `O(N)` where `N = ROWS * COLS` of the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

For copying arrays, use [`System#arrayCopy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) or [`java.util.Arrays#copyOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28T%5B%5D,%20int%29).

You cannot get an O(1) operation for copying an array. The only such way would be creating a reference: `Object[] newArray = oldArray`. This does not copy the old array. It simply points `newArray` to `oldArray`. To understand why a deep copy of O(1) is impossible, think about it on the computer's level:

When you create an array, a chunk of memory is set aside for that array. To copy each element, the computer has to go through each part of the array and copy it somewhere else (rather, each bit and copy it somewhere else). With a single element array, this only takes one operation. With a 5 element array, it takes 5 operations. Clearly, with an `n` element array, this takes `n` operations.

Thus the time complexity of copying an array has a lower bound of O(n)